# Non-standard model of arithmetic and Gödel's theorem

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, mathematicians

I've read Skolem's paper on his non-standard models of the arithmetic ("Über die Nicht-charakterisierbarkeit der Zahlenreihe mittels endlich oder abzählbar unendlich vieler Aussagen mit ausschliesslich Zahlenvariablen").

I noticed there that he is not mentioning Gödel's incompleteness theorems, though it is known that one of their consequences is the existence of a non-standard model of the arithmetic.

Does anyone know who was the first to derive that connection (between Gödel's theorem and the non-standard model)? I believe that Skolem was aware eventually was Gödel's theorems, no?

Comment: The question is duplicated on Math SE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280438/non-standard-model-of-arithmetic-and-g%C3%B6dels-theorem The answer here is only part of Math SE answer, and the part that actually answers the OP questions is missing on hsm.

Comment: @Conifold, for some strange reason the question at SME was closed.  I just voted to reopen. David can do so as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some preliminary references :

- Thoralf Skolem, (1929), Uber einige Grundlagenfragen der Mathematik. *Skrifter utgit av Det Norske Videnskaps-Akademi i Oslo I. Matematisk-naturvidenskabelig klasse*, 4, pp. 1-49.
- [Kurt Gödel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_G%C3%B6del), (1931), Über formal unentscheidbare Sätze der Principia Mathematica und verwandter Systeme, I. *Monatshefte für Mathematik und Physik* 38: 173–98.
- [Thoralf Skolem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoralf_Skolem) (1934) Über die Nicht-charakterisierbarkeit der Zahlenreihe mittels endlich oder abzählbar unendlich vieler Aussagen mit ausschliesslich Zahlenvariablen. *Fundam. Math.* 23, 150-161.

According to [Jens Erik Fenstad](http://www.hf.uio.no/ifikk/forskning/publikasjoner/tidsskrifter/njpl/vol1no2/skobio.pdf) :

> Towards the end of the 1929 paper Skolem expressed some doubts about the complete axiomatizability of mathematical concepts. His scepticism was based on the set-theoretic relativism which follows from the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem. In 1929 he could give only some partial results, but in a paper from 1934 (and a previous one from 1933) "Über die Nichtcharacterisierbarkeit der Zahlenreihe mittels endlich oder abzählbar unendlich vieler Aussagen mit ausschliesslich Zahlenvariablen" he could prove that there is no finite or countably infinite
>   set of sentences in the language of Peano arithmetic which characterizes the natural numbers. Today, this follows as a simple consequence of Gödel's completeness theorem. The technique used by Skolem was a more direct model-theoretic construction. And this technique, suitably refined to the so-called "ultraproduct" construction, has been an important tool in recent work on model theory.

---

You can see :

- Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=4GzCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1967 - Dover ed  2002), page 326-27 for a discussion of Skolem's theorem (1934) on nonstandard models of arithmetic :

> It is surprising that the existence of nonstandard models of the usual 
>   axioms of elementary number theory was not widely recognized very early 
>   by juxtaposing Gödel's completeness theorem 1930 and his incompleteness 
>   theorem 1931 [footnote].
>
> > [footnote] Not however with quite the version in Gödel 1931, where the incompleteness is given for "*Principia Mathematica* [Whitehead and Russell, 1910—13] and related systems". PM is not of the form {(first-order) predicate calculus} + {number-theoretic axiom system}. Number-theoretic systems of that form came in with Hilbert 1928, so they are sometimes called Hilbert arithmetic. In 1931-2 (reporting a colloquium held January 22, 1931), Gödel states his incompleteness theorem for such a formal system, with all the usual axioms of elementary number theory.
> >
> > When the author pointed out the connection between Skolem's and Gödel's theorems in **Introduction to metamathematics** (1952) p. 430, he knew of no earlier mention of it in the literature. Recently, he has come across 2 lines in Gödel's review of Skolem 1933 [Uber die Unmbglichkeit einer vollstdndigen Charakterisierung der Zahlenreihe mittels eines endlichen Axiomensystems] (K.Gödel, 1934, Review of Skolem 1933, *Zentralblatt fiir Mathematik und ihre Grenzgebiete*, vol. 7, pp. 193-194, p.194 lines 10-11) and 3 in Henkin 1950 (L.Henkin, [Completeness in the theory of types](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2266967?uid=3738296&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106414969211), *JSL*, vol.15, pp. 81-91, p.91 lines 8-10) alluding to such a connection.

Comment: thanks you. The question is - who first made the connection between Gödel's theorem and Skolem's Models?

Comment: Mauro, please consider "completing" your answer here (your answer to the exact duplicate over on [math.se] was more elaborate, but after talking to the math mods it was decided that "their copy" should be closed).